# Как правильно вывести в Log исключение?

Tags: android, java

Есть такая конструкция:

```
try
{
    return ...
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы исключение выводило в Log

```
try
{
    return ...
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "error!", e.printStackTrace());
}
```

Как правильно реализовать код выше?

Comment: как вариант можно использовать тот же метод printStackTrace но с параметрами:

    void printStackTrace(PrintStream s) - Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the specified print stream.
    void printStackTrace(PrintWriter s) - Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the specified print writer.

но я не уверен доступны ли они в android sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы так не советовал делать, но если хочется

```
Log.i(TAG, "" + e.getStackTrace() );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "error!!!!", e);
```

Comment: см. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 1):

Зачем мудрить то?
Есть же спецом метод

```
Log.d(TAG, "Message", e); //засовываем экспешн в последний параметр и все!
```

Comment: Это то все понятно... Вы написали то же самое, что и выше, только приоритет ошибки другой + при окончательной сборки компилятор выкидывает Log.d и он не захломляет прогу